# Not all code paths return a value for Array

Tags: c#, .net, return

I'm getting the following error:

> Not all code paths return a value for Array

Here is my code:

```
public Product[] LoadAllDatas()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=####; Integrated Security=true;Database=Store");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_LoadTestData");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            return new Product[]
            {
                new Product() { ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]), Name = dr["Name"].ToString(), AdminContent = dr["AdminComment"].ToString(), ProductTemplate = dr["ProductTemplateId"].ToString(), CreatedOnUtc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["CreatedOnUtc"]) }
            };
        }

        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Lets put the return type aside. You are using a while loop and returning one item at the best case. Read about IEnumerables and about the yield keyword since it looks like a good place to use them, or simply return instead of returning the first row, add the data to an array and return the whole array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you basically need to think about what happens if `dr.Read()` returns false - i.e. if there are no results. You may well want to throw an exception in that case... or possibly return an empty array.

Additionally, you should use `using` statements for your reader, command and your connection, to close them - currently if you *do* return a result, you don't close the connection.

Finally, you're always going to return an array which only contains a *single* `Product`. Is that really what you want? I would expect that you'd want to return an array with *all* the results.

Here's some sample code addressing all of these issues, returning an empty array in the case of no results:

```
public Product[] LoadAllDatas()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_LoadTestData", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<Product> results = new List<Product>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(new Product { 
                         ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
                         Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                         AdminContent = dr["AdminComment"].ToString(),
                         ProductTemplate = dr["ProductTemplateId"].ToString(),
                         CreatedOnUtc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["CreatedOnUtc"])
                    });
                }
                return results.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One last note - if the values in your reader are of an appropriate type, I'd expect you to be able to simplify your `Product` instantiation to:

```
new Product
{ 
     ProductId = (int) dr["Id"],
     Name = (string) dr["Name"],
     AdminContent = (string) dr["AdminComment"],
     ProductTemplate = (string) dr["ProductTemplateId"],
     CreatedOnUtc = (DateTime) dr["CreatedOnUtc"]
}
```